# Is it possible grant permission of managing the users in a specific user group?

Tags: permissions, groups

We have a group that represents all users able to use a specific business application. Permissions for the group are managed by an admin, but the actual members of the group are specified by business super-users (say, another hypothetical group called managers).

What I'd like to do is create a group of managers, and assign that group the permission to add/remove users from the application users group. However, whilst I can find how to set permissions to edit lists/libraries/pages/etc. I haven't managed to find how (or if it's possible to do at all) for groups.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a group for the super users, you should then be able to create a group for the members and set the owner as the super user group. This should allow them to manage the membership of the group without actually changing any permission levels on the site.

Comment: Many thanks - worked like a charm. Should have realised ownership could belong to a group as well.